# I want to return true if the button is clicked and also close the window onclick using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, vbscript

I want to return true if the button is clicked and also close the window onclick using JAVASCRIPT
I'm using this code to return true and close the window at once

JavaScript

```
function out()
{
    return true;
    window.close();


}
```

HTML

```
form name="remove" action="" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="text-align:center">
    <tr height="30px" id="rem">
        <td><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Remove Access" onClick="out();" /></td>

    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

but the window doesn't get closed. But it returns true. What am I missing here.

I'm updating database value on the button click if it return true i.e if it is clicked.

```
<%
    if request.form("ok") <> "" then
        sql1 = "select * from folder_access where srno = '"&request.QueryString("srno")&"'"
        rs1.open sql1, con, 1, 2
            rs1("folder_removed") = "Remove Access"
            session("ok") = "Remove Access"
        rs1.update

        rs1.close
    end if

%>
```

Comment: because you already return from the function so window.close() will not execute

Comment: There is no such thing as JAVSCRIPT. I think you mean JavaScript.

Comment: what good is a return value to a closed window? I'm sorry if I'm being thick, but what do you intend to do with the return value?

Comment: I'm using value of the button cilck to update a database filed

Answer (score 0):

And like that ?

```
function out()
{
    window.close();
    return true;
}
```

Instructions after "return" are not executed.

Comment: Why do you think it would not return true?

Comment: what do you mean it does not return true?

Comment: It does return true, but in the closed window. If you want to pass the "true" value to another window, you have to do it in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

When you return the rest of the function is canceled:

```
function out()
{
    window.close();
    return true;
}
```

But `window.close()` will try to close your current window. And the return will never be used. Because the window is closed.

---

See this example:

```
function test() {
    alert(1);
    return true;
    alert(2);
}
```

The `alert(2)` isn't executed because you already have returned:

```
function test() {
    alert(1);
    alert(2);
    return true;
}
```

Now two alerts shows.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
function out()
{    
    window.close();
    return true;
}
```

return statement makes the function exit, so any other code after return is not executed..

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened a Popup window better add a hidden field in Parent page and update it's value on out()

function out()

{

```
parent.document.getElementById('hidField').value = "true";
window.close();
```

}

Now in parent page you can get value of hidden field.